# PC Power Supply Schematic Drawing

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Anybody has a very simple Schematic drawing for PC power supply ? 
Or any basic components needed for a PC Switch Mode Power Supply Circuits . Example like rectifier , Buck Converter

Comment: They are all complicated.  Seriously.

Comment: Maybe not very simple , But at least something that is able to study through easily?

Comment: The first step ought to have been to search the web for SMPS schematics. Then, after studying what is found, if the level of complexity is not "in-over-my-head" level, please come back and ask a more specific question or five. There really haven't been simple PC power supplies since perhaps the early 1980s.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on what @AnindoGhosh said...

Learn how a typical switching DC/DC converter works.  Start with a "Buck Regulator".  Then a "Boost Regulator".  After that a "Flyback".  While these converters are generally useful things by themselves, they are also the building blocks of an AC/DC supply.

Linear Tech (linear.com) has some good parts with nice documentation.  Even better, they have a free simulator (LTSpice) and example files for all of their chips.  This is a great way to learn about these types of power supplies, and allows you to modify their circuits or make your own and see how they should operate.

Linear Tech does not do AC/DC supplies.  But TI does.  And they have quite a few app notes on the subject.  Once you have the boost/buck/flyback stuff down, look at TI for their stuff.  While this still doesn't get you to the level of "PC Power Supply", once you learn a basic AC/DC supply you will probably understand how to get to the next level on your own.